# Using HAVING with COUNT to restrict results

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to write a SQL query that would list all teachers that have more than three (3) students in their class (`Mrs. Smith` in this case). I originally thought that the `HAVING` clause would be the correct way to accomplish this but I am not coming up with `Mrs. Smith` as expected.

```
Teacher         Student
-------------------------
Mrs. Smith      Danny
Mrs. Smith      Emily
Mrs. Smith      Todd
Mrs. Smith      Paul
Mr. French      Sam
Mr. French      Carol
Mr. French      Patty

SELECT DISTINCT Teacher
FROM Students 
HAVING (COUNT(Teacher) > 3)
GROUP BY Teacher, Student
```

Comment: You need to take a count of the students.

Comment: Order's important.. Select, From, Join, Where, Group by, Having.

Comment: `group by Teacher`.  You don't want `student` in the `group by` clause.  And, remove the `distinct` from the `select`.  It is almost never needed with `group by`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using HAVING is correct, you just need to use it correctly

```
SELECT Teacher
FROM Students 
GROUP BY Teacher
HAVING COUNT(Student) > 3
```

Basically you're grouping *Teacher* records together while counting how many *Students* each teacher has. And filtering on that count.

Comment: Not sure if `COUNT(*)` or `COUNT(DISTINCT Student)` makes more sense here.  Either way it's all better than `COUNT(Teacher)`.

Comment: @ebyrob I think `COUNT(Student)` makes sense - here, we're looking for Students only and assumption is - there could be different students with the same name

Comment: `COUNT(Student)` seems confusing to me for a new SQL user.  It might be easy to think some meaning was being conveyed there, when it is merely skipping count of the (non-existant in this case) `NULL` Student rows.  The fact there is no ID for student, just a first-name, is really just a design flaw in the (presumably new) SQL user's schema.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, HAVING is correct. Try:

```
SELECT Teacher
FROM Students 
GROUP BY Teacher
HAVING (COUNT(1) > 3)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need to place your `HAVING` clause at the end:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Teacher
FROM Students 
GROUP BY Teacher, Student
HAVING COUNT(Teacher) > 3;
```

Answer (score 1):

> all **teachers**
>   that have 
>   **more than three students**

So:

```
select teacher, count(student) --All Teachers
FROM Students 
GROUP BY Teacher
HAVING COUNT(student) > 3  --Having more than three students
```

Answer (score 1):

Change it to only group by Teacher and put Having after Group By

```
SELECT Teacher
FROM Students    
GROUP BY Teacher
HAVING (COUNT(Teacher) > 3)
```