# Using HAVING to restrict results when using GROUP BY on multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

Given a list of physician and patient interaction dates (`VisitSchedule`), I want to select all those physicians who have seen more than 2 unique patients. My problem is that in order to isolate physician/patients I need to group by both physician and patient. How do I then restrict the results such that only `Dr. Moody` is returned? Since he has seen three (3) unique patients and `Dr. Franks` has seen only two (2) unique patients even though he has had more visits in total?

```
Physician      Patient       VisitDate
-------------------------------------
Dr. Moody      Danny         5/1/2013
Dr. Moody      Danny         5/3/2013
Dr. Moody      Danny         5/7/2013
Dr. Moody      Paul          4/11/2013
Dr. Moody      Paul          5/10/2013
Dr. Moody      James         5/1/2013
Dr. Franks     Allison       4/18/2013
Dr. Franks     Allison       4/24/2013
Dr. Franks     Tammy         4/11/2013
Dr. Franks     Tammy         4/14/2013
Dr. Franks     Tammy         5/11/2013
Dr. Franks     Tammy         5/12/2013
Dr. Franks     Tammy         5/17/2013

SELECT Physician
FROM VisitSchedule
GROUP BY Physician, Patient
HAVING (COUNT(Physician) > 2)
```

Am I using `COUNT` incorrectly?

Please note that my [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23663423/using-having-with-count-to-restrict-results?noredirect=1#comment36349138_23663423) was related to this one but I realized I didn't properly explain the grouping by two columns. I was trying to simplify the question as to to not make it too verbose and I ended up *over-simplifying* it.

P.S. If anyone has any suggestions on "SQL Puzzle" books that would help one practice problems like these that would be great.

Comment: `SELECT Physician FROM VisitSchedule GROUP BY Physician HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Patient) > 2`

Comment: @Lamak it's worth an answer

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Was trying to find a duplicate actually, since I'm certain this has been asked before

Comment: So it looks like my problem is that I do not need to group by Patient at all. I thought I did in order to get unique instances.

Comment: @Lamak probably so, but an explanation of why `Patient` shouldn't be in the `GROUP` is useful and distinctive

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Yeah, I know, that's why I didn't actually post an answer, but still wanted to help op

Comment: So basically the `COUNT(DISTINCT Patient)` is how to deal with multiple visits from the same patient?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You started quite good, this query should bring it to an end:

```
SELECT
    vs.Physician

FROM
    VisitSchedule vs

GROUP BY
    vs.Physician

HAVING
    COUNT(DISTINCT vs.Patient) > 2
```

Comment: why are you using `vs.` as a prefix of everything?, this will fail

Comment: Does that FROM section work like that?! I have never seen an alias assigned like that...

Comment: A agree with lamak, it would need to be "FROM VisitSchedule vs" to assign the alias.

Comment: @timo.rieber @Lamak -Thank you so much! That `group by` really messes me up at times.